# Start debugging from add-in

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-addins

I'm making VS add-in which changes debugging commandline.
This part works, but i need to start debugging after it's changed.

How do I start debugging from add-in?

mybe something from this function might help

```
Function GetCommandArgsProperty() As EnvDTE.Property
    Dim solution As Solution
    Dim project As Project
    Dim sb As SolutionBuild
    Dim cm As ConfigurationManager
    Dim config As Configuration
    Dim properties As Properties
    Dim prop As EnvDTE.Property

    solution = _applicationObject.Solution
    sb = solution.SolutionBuild

    For Each str As String In sb.StartupProjects
        project = solution.Item(str)
        cm = project.ConfigurationManager
        config = cm.ActiveConfiguration
        properties = config.Properties

        For Each prop In properties
            If prop.Name = "CommandArguments" Then
                Return prop
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it working

```
        Dim dte As EnvDTE.DTE = GetService(GetType(EnvDTE.DTE))
        dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.Run()
```